# Extracting coordinates from mapinfo map window

Tags: coordinates, mapinfo

I didn't have time to go the field to collect GPS coordinates but I have knowledge from the map where the boundary of the land of nearly 20000 hectares will follow and therefore I wish to extract coordinates for the new GPS ID or field survey stations that I will propose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a MBX tool named "Coordinate Extractor" from MapInfo tools menu. I made a screenshot from About section for you to see how to use it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the coordinates (in the map window's current coordinate system) of a specific location on the map, you can set the status bar to show you the current mouse position. Click on the section at the bottom left of the application window and select 'Cursor Location'.

[image: cursor location coordinates]